# can i send identical transaction without api ME

Tags: instructions, send-transaction, magiceden, transaction-instructions

Do I need to get instructions via the Magiceden api
to send such a transaction
solscanlink - [link](https://solscan.io/tx/67apRJqqo9pYcyriF1gsf6XesuNh1A8zVaxMRKs9v4bP6FisC7xANHeeaBBzk3jg3CVYJbxaPsbu7HpEqaXLqmYa)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, every ME transaction needs to get signed by `NTYeYJ1wr4bpM5xo6zx5En44SvJFAd35zTxxNoERYqd` as you can see on solscan. That means that you need to retrieve a partially signed transaction from ME via their API, which is heavily gated. You have to partially sign that transaction afterwards with the buyer wallet.

Comment: w/o api now way?

Comment: @plugarea no, exclusively via their API since it needs to be partially signed already